# Are there Operations Research books by world-famous authors made available on the web?

Tags: online-resources, books

Are there any books on Operations Research subjects by world-famous authors which have been made available for free access on the web, despite never having been "completed" to the standard to which the authors aspired?

I would also accept completed books as well.

Answer (score 16):

- The [Warehouse & Distribution Science](https://www.warehouse-science.com/book/index.html) by John J. Bartholdi III and Steven T. Hackman. From their site:

  > This book is a work-in-progress. We are still revising and extending the material and suggest you print only what you need as you need it.
  >
  > Version 0.98.1, released 17 August 2019

Although the question was about books not being completed, I also list the following books that are available online for free and they are from famous authors, in case someone finds them useful.

- Several books by Dimitri P. Bertsekas which their pdf copies can be accessed from [this link](http://www.mit.edu/~dimitrib/books.htm) including:

  - Network Optimization: Continuous and Discrete Models ([link](http://web.mit.edu/dimitrib/www/net.html))
  - Convex Optimization Theory ([link](http://web.mit.edu/dimitrib/www/Convex_Alg_Chapters.html))
  - Constrained Optimization and Lagrange Multiplier Methods ([link](http://web.mit.edu/dimitrib/www/lagr_mult.html))

Answer (score 13):

Just posted on January 16, 2020:

[Elements of Scheduling, collected and edited by Jan Karel Lenstra and David B. Shmoys](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/2001/2001.06005.pdf)

> This {pdf file} presents the fragments of a book on machine scheduling.
> Work on the book started in 1977 but was never completed. The existing
> material is now made available for teaching purposes.
>
> In the winter of 1976, Alexander Rinnooy Kan and Jan Karel Lenstra
> defended their PhD theses at the University of Amsterdam. Gene Lawler
> was on their committees. It was a natural idea to turn the theses into
> a textbook on scheduling. They set out to compile a survey with Ron
> Graham (1979), but progress on the book was hampered by the many
> research opportunities offered by the field. After David Shmoys joined
> the team in the mid 1980's, several chapters were drafted, and the
> survey was rewritten (1993). Gene passed away in 1994. Colleagues were
> asked to contribute chapters or to complete existing drafts. However,
> by the turn of the century the project was losing its momentum, and
> finite convergence to completion fell beyond our reach. Over the
> years, several chapters have been used in the classroom. We continue
> to receive requests from colleagues who look for a text on the
> elements of scheduling at an advanced undergraduate or early graduate
> level. This document is a compilation of what currently exists. We
> have made a marginal effort in patching it up at some places but is
> essentially what was written long ago. We did make an attempt to
> include most of the citations in the bibliography.

**Edit**: Completed books:

[Convex Optimization, by Boyd and Vandenberghe](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/)

Comment: sorry. It was not intentional at first. I know you're a fan of one-stop shops. But, if you think it's better to have a separate question for the completed books, then we can revert.

Comment: @EhsanK I'm fine with the expansion. I originally made it narrow, in part to attempt to appease the "too broad" crowd.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best one is [here](http://pourghaderi.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Wiliams-Model-Building-in-Mathematical-Programming-5th-2013.pdf):
Model Building in Mathematical Programming.

Comment: Ledt unsaid in my question is "legally" available. Dies this qualify?